# OpenCV CalcCovarMatrix vs. Numpy Cov

Tags: python, c++, opencv, numpy

I am porting an image processing algorithm from Python to C++, using OpenCV in both cases.

In the Python version, we are using np.cov from Numpy:

```
import numpy as np
#Using some dummy data to represent BGR pixels
values = [[30, 37, 35], [26, 36, 34], [38, 45, 41], [40, 47, 43], [38, 45, 43], [34, 43, 40], [30, 39, 37]]
result = np.cov(values, rowvar=False) #Using default 1/(N-1) normalisation
print result
```

which produces the output:

```
[[ 27.23809524  22.23809524  18.66666667]
 [ 22.23809524  18.9047619   15.83333333]
 [ 18.66666667  15.83333333  13.66666667]]
```

In the C++ version, we are using calcCovarMatrix from OpenCV:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main() {
  Mat values(7, 3, CV_8UC1);
  //Representing the same pixels as the Python code
  values.at<uchar>(0) = (30, 37, 35);
  values.at<uchar>(1) = (26, 36, 34);
  values.at<uchar>(2) = (38, 45, 41);
  values.at<uchar>(3) = (40, 47, 43);
  values.at<uchar>(4) = (38, 45, 43);
  values.at<uchar>(5) = (34, 43, 40);
  values.at<uchar>(6) = (30, 39, 37);

  Mat avgs, covars;
  calcCovarMatrix(values, covars, avgs, CV_COVAR_NORMAL | CV_COVAR_SCALE | CV_COVAR_ROWS);
  cout << covars << "\n";
  calcCovarMatrix(values, covars, avgs, CV_COVAR_NORMAL | CV_COVAR_ROWS);
  cout << covars << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

which produces the output:

```
[364.8163265306122, 253.4285714285715, 260.6122448979592;
 253.4285714285715, 308.2857142857143, 317.5714285714286;
 260.6122448979592, 317.5714285714286, 334.8163265306122]
[2553.714285714286, 1774, 1824.285714285714;
 1774, 2158, 2223;
 1824.285714285714, 2223, 2343.714285714285]
```

As can be seen, the C++ output does not match the Python output at all. Scaling or not in calcCovarMatrix doesn't seem to correct it, setting a ddof or not in np.cov doesn't seem to correct it either. Any ideas?

Note: for whatever reason, np.cov and calcCovarMatrix use contradictory interpretations of "row"; in both input cases, each *row* represents an observation, and each *column* represents a variable, so in Numpy we set rowvar=False but in calcCovarMatrix we set CV_COVAR_ROWS (to be True). I don't think that this is the source of the problem.

Comment: Try using that OpenCV function `calcCovarMatrix` in Python too, what results does it give?

Comment: I'm struggling to find correct documentation. All the docs say `cv2.calcCovarMatrix(samples, flags[, covar[, mean[, ctype]]]) → covar, mean` but the actual definition in my built library is `cv2.calcCovarMatrix(samples, mean, flags[, covar[, ctype]]) → covar, mean` and mean is a required argument? So I am getting errors (even after supplying the mean) and can't figure out why...

Comment: `Unsupported combination of input and output array formats in function reduce` when running matrix.cpp

Comment: Fixed, for whatever reason the input numbers have to be floats for calcCovarMatrix to work.

Comment: Python OpenCV calcCovarMatrix produces something different again:
`[[ 163.42857143  133.42857143  112. ]
 [ 133.42857143  113.42857143   95.]
 [ 112.  95.  82.]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit has been identified! There were two problems:

1) `values.at<uchar>(0) = (30, 37, 35);` does not in fact write the values into the row (as someone coming in from Python would expect). It actually just writes the last value, 35, into the 0th position of the Mat. The Mat in the above code actually resolves to:

```
`[35,  34,  41;
  43,  43,  40;
  37,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0]`
```

2) The OpenCV CalcCovarMatrix is not normalised. `covars/(values.rows-1)` fixes this and produces the same output as Python Numpy.